# Server not accepting big files

Tags: php, file, upload, size

I try to upload big (>~1.5MB) images to my website (free hosting) using PHP but the file dont appear on the server.
Sometimes I get Error 1 (Max size exceeded), and sometimes it tells me that `move_uploaded_file()` succeeded but the image still doesnt appear.
When I try to set the `PHP.ini` to more than 2M upload size, it gets back to 2M.
Is there any thing I can do ?
Tnx.

Comment: Have you checked that your host allows you to host large files?

Comment: Since its free hosting, there is size limit to file uploads. Many free hosting offer only 2 mb.

Comment: Change hosts. some of those free hosts lockdown what you are able to do on purpose so that the service can't be exploited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set them in **.htaccess** or with (it can be done only with post_max_size) [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set)

If it doesn't work then it means that your provider disabled it.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Lines to add to .htaccess

**Notice:** upload_max_filesize is type of **PHP_INI_PERDIR** which means that it can be set in in **php.ini**, **.htaccess**, **httpd.conf** or **.user.ini** (since PHP 5.3)

- [Configuration modes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)
- [List of settings that can be changed in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

Comment: This wont work on hosting providers they explicitly prohibit such behavior

Comment: @php_nub_qq that is why I wrote that if it doesn't work it means that provider forbids it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue with hosting providers, you need a local `php.ini` file in order to be able to overwrite stuff given from the main `php.ini`. Using `ini_set()` wont work on cases like that. If you do have your local `php.ini` and it's still not working it is best you contact your provider and ask them how to manage further.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to change couple of configuration directive from `php.ini` those are as follows

```
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Given that your using free hosting you may not have access to change the php.ini file, if that is the case then you could possibly use an `.htaccess` file to override the values.

`upload_max_filesize` has a PHP_INI_PERDIR changeable state which means it is not possible to change via `ini_set` and can be changed in the following places. Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini

Comment: That value is not staying which suggest the host has a configuration system that reverts changes to the php.ini.

Comment: It is not possible to change `upload_max_filesize` with php.ini check manual!

Comment: @Robert check my updated answer, i was in the process of updating my answer when you downvoted me.